# Web page sections with parallax are lagging when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

My page ([link](http://karpacz-szklarska.pl/test/parallax/)) has a parallax scrolling effect between it's 4 sections (sections 2nd, 3rd and 4th scroll a bit faster, and each section overlaps the previous one). Here's the js code responsible for parallax:

```
$(function() {    
    basePadTop1 = parseInt($(".section_first").css("paddingTop").split("px")[0]);
    baseTop2 = parseInt($(".section_second").css("marginTop").split("px")[0]);
    baseTop3 = parseInt($(".section_third").css("marginTop").split("px")[0]);
    baseTop4 = parseInt($(".section_fourth").css("marginTop").split("px")[0]);

    $(window).on("scroll ready", function() {

        if($(window).width() > 1030) {

            var actPos = $(window).scrollTop();
            scrPadTop1 = basePadTop1 - actPos;
            scrTop2 = baseTop2 - actPos;
            scrTop3 = (baseTop3 - actPos)*1.55;
            scrTop4 = (baseTop4 - actPos)*2.25;

            if(actPos > scrTop4) {
                return;
            }

            $(".section_first").css("paddingTop", scrPadTop1 + "px");
            $(".section_second").css("marginTop", scrTop2 + "px");
            $(".section_third").css("marginTop", scrTop3 + "px");
            $(".section_fourth").css("marginTop", scrTop4 + "px");

        }           
    }); 
});
```

It works quite nice, except for one issue in Firefox.

As long as the page is scrolled using keyboard arrows or mousewheel it's fine, but if you slowly drag the scrollbar, section 3rd and 4th are lagging. This issue doesn't appear on Chrome.

I tried to fix it by making the accelerated scroll independent from scrollTop(), but it didn't solve the issue.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the GPu for hardware acceleration using the following code in the css class you use for this:

```
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
   -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
   -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
   -o-transform: translateZ(0);
   transform: translateZ(0);
```

Hope it helps you...

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem. But thanks for this tip, I'll keep it mind.